# How to change horizontal alignment for \frac?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

Typing \frac{W+W^*}{2} gives $\frac{W+W^*}{2}$ in which the denominator appears to the eye to be in the wrong position. Is there a way to correct this, ie place the 2 in under the + (without using arbitrary negative spacing)?

Comment: Also, I disagree that the denominator looks wrong.

Comment: I agree that the 2 is in the wrong place, and I've complained about this behaviour of latex for a long time. You can always try \frac{W+W^*}{2~~} which gives $\frac{W+W^*}{2~~}$. Not perfect as the bar is too long. Also \frac{W+W}{2}^* gives $\frac{W+W}{2}^*$, which is cheating but works.

Comment: Also, i'm interested in better answers than mine, and think this is a pretty good question.